# How to produce {{1,40},{2,20}} from {{1, 10}, {2, 20}, {1, 30}}?

Tags: list-manipulation, code-review

My attempt below produced  a warning:

> Total::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in Total[y].

```
ClearAll[a,b,data];
a={1,2,1};
b={10,20,30};
data=Thread[{a,b}];
Normal@GroupBy[data, First -> Last] /. (x_ -> y_) -> {x, Total[y]}
```

Output:

```
{{1,40},{2,20}}
```

I am not happy enough with this. I believe there will be much better or correct way to produce the  required output.

Comment: How about `GroupBy[data, First -> Last, Total]`. If you really want a list instead of the probably more useful Association, you can do `KeyValueMap[List] @ GroupBy[data, First -> Last, Total]`

Comment: @CarlWoll: Thank you very much. It works.

Comment: try also `KeyValueMap[List]@Merge[Total][Rule @@@ data]`

Comment: @kglr: Thank you very much. If `data` is previously obtained from `data=Thread[{a,b}]` where `a={1,2,1}` and `b={10,20,30}`, will the process of getting `{{1,40},{2,20}}` become much easier by using only `a` and `b` (without `data`)? I am interested in making the code much more efficient. In other words, I am interested in eliminating the step `data=Thread[{a,b}]`.

Comment: maybe `KeyValueMap[List]@Merge[Total][Thread[a->b]]`?

Comment: @kglr: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f1 = KeyValueMap[List] @* Merge[Total] @* Thread @* Rule;

f1[a, b]
```

> ```
> {{1, 40}, {2, 20}}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
ClearAll[data, newdata];
data = {{1, 10}, {2, 20}, {1, 30}};
newdata = GatherBy[data, First];
{#[[1, 1]], #[[All, -1]] // Total} & /@ newdata
```

> `{{1, 40}, {2, 20}}`

Answer (score 2):

```
data = {{1, 10}, {2, 20}, {1, 30}};
assoc = GroupBy[data, First -> Last];
{#, Total[assoc[#]]} & /@ Keys[assoc]
```

> ```
> {{1, 40}, {2, 20}}
> ```